# Dynamics 365 CRM: Limit active languages in UI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In our Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM environment we have multiple languages installed and activated.
We need them for our portals application.
In the CRM we do not want the user to be able to select all of the active languages, but some of them.

Is there a way to limit the lanugages shown in the dropdown?
Or is there any other way to prevent the selection?

We tried to do the second point by adding a plugin that throws an InvalidPluginExecutionException when selecting another language, but it does not give any feedback to the user.

Comment: under which entity you attached the plugin?

Comment: @GuidoPreite We added the plugin to update of the usersetting entity

Comment: the entity is correct, technically it should work but I never tried myself. I don't see other ways to limit the language of the users

Comment: Is it sync or Async plugin ? anything on Plugin trace ?

Comment: @ArunVinoth-PrecogTech-MVP The plugin is sync. You can see the message of the exception in the trace log. It works, but the user does not get presented with a message in the frontend. When they click on 'ok' to save, just nothing happens. When they select a valid language, then clicking on 'ok' closes the frame and does the saving.

Comment: @Lars-PascalKörber yeah probably the page refresh (happens after any personal settings changed) is avoiding the popup, but not sure.